# FFMPEG converting mix mp3

Tags: ffmpeg

Here goes  : taking a vaw file and converting 0 to 10 sec new mp3

```
exec("d:/wamp/ffmpg/bin/ffmpeg -ss 0 -i $vaw -t 10  -y -id3v2_version 3  $newMp3 2>&1",$a,$b);
```

But how can we do

converting first 0 to 10 and 25 to 50 and 95 to 110 sec creating mix new mp3

Like this

```
exec("d:/wamp/ffmpg/bin/ffmpeg -ss 0,25,50 -i $vaw -t 10,50,110  -y -id3v2_version 3  $newMp3 2>&1",$a,$b);
```

Comment: There  are any person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`atrim` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim) to select segments, and the [`concat` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) to concatenate them. This example will select durations (in seconds) of 0-10, 25-50, and 95-110:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"[0:a]atrim=0:10,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; \
 [0:a]atrim=25:50,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]; \
 [0:a]atrim=95:110,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a3]; \
 [a1][a2][a3]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[out]" \
-map "[out]" output.mp3
```

- Because `atrim` does not modify the timestamps, and since all segments must start at timestamp 0 for `concat` to work correctly, the [`asetpts` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) is added to start counting the presentation timestamp from zero.
- For reference, if you wanted 95-end, you would use: `atrim=start=95`.
- Your issue really has nothing to do with programming, so it is offtopic for Stack Overflow, but since it's your first post I'll provide an answer. Try [Super User](https://superuser.com/tags/ffmpeg) next time for `ffmpeg` cli help.